# Determinant of a matrix with trigonometry functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, determinant

> Prove that the matrix is invertible for any value of $\beta$.

I've done several exercises of this type. But I'm not sure with this one:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos \beta & \sin \beta & 0\\ -\sin\beta & \cos \beta & 0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

My knowledge of trigonometric functions is pretty poor, but anyway, let's see:

The matrix would be invertible if its determinant is $\not = 0$. The determinant of this matrix is equivalent to

$$(\cos\beta \cdot \cos \beta) - (\sin \beta \cdot -\sin\beta)$$

Alright, I'm not sure what am I doing. Surely there is a basic law I'm missing, but I can't quite grasp it.

Comment: $-(\sin \beta \cdot (- \sin \beta)) = (\sin \beta)^2$. Then use $\sin ^2 + \cos ^2 = 1$

Comment: Old question, but might help someone at some point: the geometric perspective for why this is invertible is that the matrix represents a [rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) in the $xy$ plane by $\beta$ radians anticlockwise. This is naturally reversible---just rotate back by $\beta$ radians clockwise, and that's your inverse transformation.

Answer (score 1):

The basic law that you're missing is $\cos^2 \beta + \sin^2 \beta = 1$ for any $\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

It is an orthogonal matrix, since the dot product of any two columns is zero and the euclidean norm of any column is one. Hence such a matrix represents an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$, hence it is invertible.

---

Someone thinks this is nuking mosquitoes. Ok, let us make things *easier*.

The determinant of such a matrix is $\cos^2\beta+\sin^2\beta$. Hence, by the Pythagorean theorem, the determinant of the matrix is always one, hence the matrix is invertible.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but this appears to be proving what the OP is asked to by using properties which are harder to prove than what the OP is asked to prove.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote a comment but forgot to hit post: the answer is overly technical for the level of the question, IMO. It's like trying to prove the fundamental theorem of arithmetic by considering $\mathbb{Q}$ as a quadratic field. It certainly proves it but is a long, complicated, way around

Comment: @StijnHanson: I updated my answer. Better, now?